# How to test if request has been executed with specific parametrs

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to mock node-fetch and test which headers and method were passed to it.

Code that i'm trying to test

```
export default class Client {
    baseUrl = 'https://sample.com';
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    async request({ endpoint, params, method = 'GET' }) {
        const url = new URL(`${this.baseUrl}/${endpoint}`);

        if (method === 'GET' && params) {
            url.search = new URLSearchParams(params);
        }

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method,
            headers: this.headers,
            ...(method !== 'GET' ? { body: JSON.stringify(params) } : {})
        });

        return response.json();
    }
}
```

My test file

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        json: async () => ({ status: 200 })
    })
);
const client = new Client();

it('tests client', async () => {
    const meta = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    const headers = new Headers(meta);
    const req = { headers: meta, method: 'GET' };
    const reqGet = await client.request({ endpoint: 'api/v2' });
    expect(reqGet.status).toBe(200);
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${client.baseUrl}/api/v2`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: meta
    });
});
```

The problem begins when I pass an object to `toHaveBeenCalledWith` it seems like it ignores it and only shows that expected baseUrl without any parameters.

My second try was to pass objects like so

```
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        `${client.baseUrl}/api/v2`,
        expect.objectContaining({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: meta
        })
    );
```

And this is the output from a jest

```
 Expected: "https://sample.com/api/v2", ObjectContaining {"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "method": "GET"}
 Received: "https://sample.com/api/v2", {"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "method": "GET"}
```

Comment: You're comparing a URL object with a string - they _look_ the same, but they're not equal.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hey would like to say thank you one more time and I have one more question. I encountered a problem that when I use import in my client like this `import fetch from node-fetch` it make an actual request to a server instead of mocking, but with `import 'node-fetch'` it works fine, do you know why is that happening?